# Calculate Mean Values For Every Hour to eliminate peaks and lows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, logging

I have a log file that looks like this: (Date/Time - Temperature - Humidity)

```
2016-05-17 21:17    18.5    39.2
2016-05-17 21:18    18.5    39.2
2016-05-17 21:19    18.6    39.3
2016-05-17 21:20    18.5    39.3
2016-05-17 21:21    18.5    39.3
2016-05-17 21:22    18.4    39.2
2016-05-17 21:23    18.5    39.3
2016-05-17 21:24    18.4    39.3
2016-05-17 21:25    18.5    39.4
2016-05-17 21:26    18.4    39.3
2016-05-17 21:27    18.3    39.4
2016-05-17 21:28    18.3    39.4
2016-05-17 21:29    18.4    39.5
2016-05-17 21:30    4.4 39.5
2016-05-17 21:31    18.4    39.5
2016-05-17 21:32    18.3    39.5
2016-05-17 21:33    18.3    39.5
2016-05-17 21:34    18.3    39.5
2016-05-17 21:35    18.3    39.5
2016-05-17 21:36    18.3    39.6
2016-05-17 21:37    18.3    39.6
2016-05-17 21:38    18.3    39.6
2016-05-17 21:39    18.3    39.6
2016-05-17 21:40    18.3    15.6
2016-05-17 21:41    18.2    39.5
```

I want to eliminate the rows that show unusual spikes and lows (wrong measurements).

My approach:

Calculate mean temperature and humidity values for each hour and than compare each value within this hour with the average. If either Temperature or Humidity is to far off from the mean the whole row gets kicked.

Can I do this with pandas?

So far I only got the df set up.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Logger.csv',delimiter="\t", names =['Timestamp', 'Temperature', 
'Humidity'],header=None, parse_dates=["Timestamp"], index_col="Timestamp").resample('H')
.mean().dropna()
```

So I get the mean values for every hour.

**Question:** Can I use pandas to compare every Temp and Hum value per row and eliminate those values that are 5°C or 5% off the calculated mean?

Edit: So I posted a bit more from the log file and "added" 2 measurement errors at 21:30 and 21:40. Those measurement errors occur once or twice a day and those are the rows I want to eliminate.
The data is logged 24/7 via Raspberry Pi and a DHT22 Sensor (the sensor has a bug which leads to those wrong measurements)

Not quite sure I understand your question. I want to write the good data into a new .csv file (good data.csv) and the bad data into a different new .csv file (baddata.csv)
Sorry If I got your question wrong.

Id like to calculate the mean for every 60 Minutes within the log file, and than compare the values row by row with the mean of the corresponding hour.
For the log example on top panda gives me:

```
                     Temperature  Humidity
Timestamp                                 
2016-05-17 21:00:00        17.82    38.464
```

so my idea for cleaning the log would be to compare every Temperature value within the Date 2016-05-17 and the hour 21:00 - 22:00 with 17.82°C. 
The same I would like to do with the Humidity.

And this whole process for every hour on every day in the log file.

I am sorry if I did not state that clear enough.

@ Kyle: I thought I could play around a bit with that variance. Maybe 5 °C was a bit to narrow but I think 10°C could do the job and maybe 10% Humidtiy. 
The Log is taken in a closed garage no I think hat should work. The measurement errors I want to get rid of a rather big exemptions from the regular measured values.
@MaxU:
So I tried the code but it  did not work, I played around with it to understand the syntax and this is what I ended up with:

```
logfile =pd.read_csv('/Users/Peter/Desktop/LearnPython/DataLoggerTEST.csv',header=None, delimiter="\t",names['Timestamp','Temperature','Humidity'],index_col=0,parse_dates='Timestamp')

df=[logfile[['Temperature','Humidity']].groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1H')).transform('mean').abs().query('Temperature > 5 and Humidity > 5').index]
```

all I get is the `mean` value for every hour
the output is (extract):

```
Date/Time                                 
2016-05-17 21:17:00        17.82    38.464
2016-05-17 21:18:00        17.82    38.464
2016-05-17 21:19:00        17.82    38.464
2016-05-17 21:20:00        17.82    38.464
2016-05-17 21:21:00        17.82    38.464
2016-05-17 21:22:00        17.82    38.464
2016-05-17 21:23:00        17.82    38.464
2016-05-17 21:24:00        17.82    38.464
2016-05-17 21:25:00        17.82    38.464
2016-05-17 21:26:00        17.82    38.464
2016-05-17 21:27:00        17.82    38.464
```

It seems like the part where I should get the absolute difference between `mean` value and actual value doesn't work

Comment: Can you post bit bigger sample DF and desired DF? Do you want to filter the original DF or after resampling?

Comment: `eliminate those values that are 5°C or 5% off the calculated mean` - do you mean a global `mean` for the whole DF?

Comment: You will want to determine an acceptable variance, if a record exceeds the acceptable variance you could then write it to the bad data

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is the prettiest / most elegant solution, but it should do the job:

Code:

```
df.ix[(df[['Temp','Hum']]
       -
       df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1H', key='Timestamp')).transform('mean')
      ).abs()
       .query('Temp < 5 and Hum < 5')
       .index
     ]
```

**Solution:**

```
In [115]: df.ix[(df[['Temp','Hum']]
   .....:        -
   .....:        df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1H', key='Timestamp')).transform('mean')
   .....:       ).abs()
   .....:        .query('Temp < 5 and Hum < 5')
   .....:        .index
   .....:      ]
Out[115]:
             Timestamp  Temp   Hum
0  2016-05-17 20:17:00  18.5  39.2
1  2016-05-17 20:18:00  18.5  39.2
2  2016-05-17 20:19:00  18.6  39.3
3  2016-05-17 20:20:00  18.5  39.3
4  2016-05-17 21:21:00  18.5  39.3
5  2016-05-17 21:22:00  18.4  39.2
6  2016-05-17 21:23:00  18.5  39.3
7  2016-05-17 21:24:00  18.4  39.3
8  2016-05-17 21:25:00  18.5  39.4
9  2016-05-17 21:26:00  18.4  39.3
10 2016-05-17 21:27:00  18.3  39.4
11 2016-05-17 21:28:00  18.3  39.4
12 2016-05-17 21:29:00  18.4  39.5
14 2016-05-17 21:31:00  18.4  39.5
15 2016-05-17 21:32:00  18.3  39.5
16 2016-05-17 21:33:00  18.3  39.5
17 2016-05-17 21:34:00  18.3  39.5
18 2016-05-17 21:35:00  18.3  39.5
19 2016-05-17 21:36:00  18.3  39.6
20 2016-05-17 21:37:00  18.3  39.6
21 2016-05-17 21:38:00  18.3  39.6
22 2016-05-17 21:39:00  18.3  39.6
24 2016-05-17 21:41:00  18.2  39.5
```

**Explanation:** the following expression will give us the absolute difference between the actual value and a mean value (for the corresponding hour):

```
In [119]: (df[['Temp','Hum']]
   .....:  -
   .....:  df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1H', key='Timestamp')).transform('mean')
   .....: ).abs()
Out[119]:
         Temp        Hum
0    0.025000   0.050000
1    0.025000   0.050000
2    0.075000   0.050000
3    0.025000   0.050000
4    0.814286   0.985714
5    0.714286   0.885714
6    0.814286   0.985714
7    0.714286   0.985714
8    0.814286   1.085714
9    0.714286   0.985714
10   0.614286   1.085714
11   0.614286   1.085714
12   0.714286   1.185714
13  13.285714   1.185714
14   0.714286   1.185714
15   0.614286   1.185714
16   0.614286   1.185714
17   0.614286   1.185714
18   0.614286   1.185714
19   0.614286   1.285714
20   0.614286   1.285714
21   0.614286   1.285714
22   0.614286   1.285714
23   0.614286  22.714286
24   0.514286   1.185714
```

data:

```
In [116]: df
Out[116]:
             Timestamp  Temp   Hum
0  2016-05-17 20:17:00  18.5  39.2
1  2016-05-17 20:18:00  18.5  39.2
2  2016-05-17 20:19:00  18.6  39.3
3  2016-05-17 20:20:00  18.5  39.3
4  2016-05-17 21:21:00  18.5  39.3
5  2016-05-17 21:22:00  18.4  39.2
6  2016-05-17 21:23:00  18.5  39.3
7  2016-05-17 21:24:00  18.4  39.3
8  2016-05-17 21:25:00  18.5  39.4
9  2016-05-17 21:26:00  18.4  39.3
10 2016-05-17 21:27:00  18.3  39.4
11 2016-05-17 21:28:00  18.3  39.4
12 2016-05-17 21:29:00  18.4  39.5
13 2016-05-17 21:30:00   4.4  39.5
14 2016-05-17 21:31:00  18.4  39.5
15 2016-05-17 21:32:00  18.3  39.5
16 2016-05-17 21:33:00  18.3  39.5
17 2016-05-17 21:34:00  18.3  39.5
18 2016-05-17 21:35:00  18.3  39.5
19 2016-05-17 21:36:00  18.3  39.6
20 2016-05-17 21:37:00  18.3  39.6
21 2016-05-17 21:38:00  18.3  39.6
22 2016-05-17 21:39:00  18.3  39.6
23 2016-05-17 21:40:00  18.3  15.6
24 2016-05-17 21:41:00  18.2  39.5
```

PS i've intentionally edited first 3 rows, so we would have data for at least two hours, when groupped:

```
In [117]: df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1H', key='Timestamp')).mean()
Out[117]:
                          Temp        Hum
Timestamp
2016-05-17 20:00:00  18.525000  39.250000
2016-05-17 21:00:00  17.685714  38.314286
```

Comment: I can't get it to work because I'm struggling with your way of writing the code but I guess that's what I was looking for :-)  I'll have to play with it a bit to see if it works. Is it in python 3? I am getting errors with the brackets